# Using Core Audio to extract float from default line out sound device

Tags: c++, c, macos, core-audio

I am in need for some assistance/guidance with using Core Audio to extract floats from the sound out device. I have read similar posts regarding the extraction of floats from AIFF. My end goal is something along the lines of:

- iTunes is playing a song
- C/C++ program using Core Audio
  extracts float values from the sound
  device (in real-time)
- Use resulting float vector to perform
  Fourier Transformation on a array of
  floats (probably using vDSP from
  Apple's Accelerate Library) - This part I have somewhat figured out :)

Note: I am developing on Mac OS X (10.6+).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question comes up frequently on the Core Audio mailing list.  There is no easy way to accomplish what you want to do.  See:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2007/Jul/msg00066.html
http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2009/Nov/msg00308.html

You'll need to write either a kext or a user-land driver.

Comment: Thank-you, I will look into those links. Do you think other audio libraries such as Port Audio would make this task easier?

Comment: I don't think so, because what you want to do is inherently specific to OS X.