# Audio Spectrum using JACK and fftw in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, macos, fftw, jack

I am in need of assistance (documentation, sample code, etc.) in how to develop a audio spectrum using JACK and fftw in C/C++. I am developing on Mac OS X (10.6+). Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "develop a audio spectrum" ? Are you trying to *measure* and/or *display* an audio power spectrum, perhaps ?

Comment: Yes; sorry for the lack of clarification. An example would be the one found in iTunes (in the currently playing song info window). I already know how to apply a window function and Fourier transformation and draw the data. What I really need help with is how to extract floats from the default line out on the sound device.

Comment: @Agent0: OK - you should probably edit your question and add that clarification. Good luck.

Comment: Looks like a re-statement of your previous question though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287523/using-core-audio-to-extract-float-from-default-line-out-sound-device ?

Comment: Pardon the confusion, but it is not a restatement of my previous question because my previous question dealt with Core Audio where as this is one is with the JACK audio library.

Comment: @Agent0: OK - I would drop the part about FFTW and displaying an audio spectrum though, since it sounds like you have this part nailed already, and just want to be able to get at audio samples from the current output device in one way or another ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a fantastic walkthrough of a jack tutorial here:

http://dis-dot-dat.net/index.cgi?item=/jacktuts/starting/

This should demonstrate how to build a jack application capable of grabbing audio from your system inputs and/or any jack-aware audio player.

Comment: Note, that tutorial doesn't seem to mention that JACK callbacks happen in their own thread so don't call into anything that can't handle that from inside them (eg: GUI libs).

Comment: Interesting point. Why would GUI libs struggle to handle calls from inside a different thread?

Comment: they generally don't do any locking (partially so you could use them without compiling with `-pthreads`, partially for performance, and last because it's probably really easy to create deadlocks if you're not aware of how the GUI does it's locking).

Comment: Essentially it's just one of those things where it's better to deal with it another way in almost every case, it can be REALLY hard to get locking right for event handlers.  Best thing look into how to inject events or idle callbacks from off the main threads, eg: `g_idle_add()` for GLib/GTK+